# Why does group by and sort by give 0 response

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

The result of this query gives me 0 rows where it should give me the 3 latest rows (grouped by Table1.Name). 
Table1 has: "Name", "Timestamp", "Voltage".
Table2 has: "Name", "data".

When I delete "ORDER BY Table1.Timestamp" I do get 3 rows (as expected) but they are the 3 oldest entries in the database where I want the 3 latest.
(I have 3 Name values in Table1 and Table2 that match).

The code:

```
SELECT * from Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Name=Table2.Name
GROUP BY Table1.Name
ORDER BY Table1.Timestamp;
```

Comment: *"but they are the 3 oldest entries in the database where I want the 3 latest."* -- this **is not** a job for `GROUP BY`. `GROUP BY` doesn't return rows from the database. It generates the values it returns using the values from the database.

Comment: Search for a similar question tagged with [tag:greatest-n-per-group].

Comment: If you're still struggling, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to perform a query like this :

```
SELECT t.*,t2.* from Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t.Name=t2.Name
WHERE t.Timestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(t3.Timestamp) FROM Table1 t3
    WHERE t3.Name = t.Name
)
```

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR your code works!! Thank you so much. Do you happen to know why it takes about 20 seconds to process?

Comment: It depends on the number of rows you have in your database. Try to remove the GROUP BY statement !

Comment: I have only 4000 rows.

Comment: You can put indexes on your Name and Timestamp columns ;-)

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR thanks again for your help!! Kudos!! I'm unable to retrieve the Table2.data field. Do you know how I can add Table2.data to the query results?

Comment: SELECT t.*, t2.* from Table1 t
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
ON t.Name=t2.Name
WHERE t.Timestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(t3.Timestamp) FROM Table1 t3
    WHERE t3.Name = t.Name
)

Comment: @GuillaumeSTLR that works.. thanks again! Topic can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort and taking the top 3:

```
SELECT * from Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Name=Table2.Name
ORDER BY Table1.Timestamp DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using join two or more tables then don't use * in select query. Use specific column name to avoid column ambiguously in select query , you can also use Table1.*, Table2.* but good way to use specific columns in select query.

SELECT Table1.Name,Table1.Timestamp from Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Name=Table2.Name
GROUP BY Table1.Name
ORDER BY Table1.Timestamp;